# Shell not recognised by configuration scripts

Tags: bash, install-from-source, configure

When I try to compile different packages from source (e.g., `ipsec-tools`, `openvpn`, etc.) I obtain always the same error from the configuration script:

```
$ ./configure

./configure: This script requires a shell more modern than all
./configure: the shells that I found on your system.
./configure: Please tell ****@***.org and
./configure: ***@***.org about your system, including
./configure: any error possibly output before this message. Then
./configure: install a modern shell, or manually run the script
./configure: under such a shell if you do have one.
```

On my system I've a bash shell (`GNU bash version 3.00`).

Looking at those config scripts I've noticed they support bash v.2, so I don't understand where the problem could be.

Comment: No, I don't get any permission denied error. Also, the ownerhip settings of `/dev/null` are correct...

Comment: does `echo $CONFIG_SHELL` show anything?

Comment: nope, it doesn't show anything

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks for the tip. I've solved this problem forcing the autoconf to use bash: `CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/bash ./configure`

Answer (score 1):

Bash 3.00 is quite old (six years or so); I have 4.2 which is already three years old.

Try to use a newer bash; if that fails, try zsh and ksh, both of which can be installed in your Ubuntu with `apt-get install ksh` and `apt-get install zsh`, respectively.

Comment: sadly, this is not an option at the moment. I've to stick with bash 3.00

Comment: Well, you could try to go to line 236 of the autoconf configure script and remove it (the line is `exit 1` at the end of the conditional that gives you the error). You will still see the error message, but the configure script will continue.